# How to update picture in c# while code running

Tags: c#, image, xaml, user-interface

```
string fileName = "Picture.bmp";
            byte[] picture = new byte[9000000];
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] PictureBits;
            Debug.WriteLine(ip);
            s = new SocketHandler(ip, Int32.Parse(port));
            PictureBits = s.recive();
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, PictureBits);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //will sleep for 5 sec
            screenShot.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"bin\Debug\Picture.bmp", UriKind.Relative));
```

```
<Window x:Class="RJviewClient.streamImage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RJviewClient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="streamImage" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="screenShot" Source="bin\Debug\s.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="286,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

even when I display an image from begging when I run the code the pic disperse

now when the code is running I cant update while it works.
how do I do it?

Comment: We don't know what is the context. Are you trying to read and update an image stored locally? Why is `user-interface` tagged?

Comment: Presumably this code-fragment is running on the UI thread and therefore blocking it, but you should really show more code. For example how `screenShot` is used in your UI.